# US born but as a child of foreign diplomat

Tags: usa

I was born in the US as a child of a foreign diplomat.  I recently became a Canadian citizen and the passport shows the birth place as NY USA.  Obviously, I am not and cannot be a US citizen according to the US constitution.  As all US citizens are required to enter the US with their passports, but I am not, will I have issues at the US border; and could being the offspring of a foreign diplomat be explanation enough?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93237/discussion-on-question-by-jay-han-us-born-but-as-a-child-of-foreign-diplomat).

Answer (score 32):

You will not have trouble entering the US. If you are questioned about your birthplace, you simply state the facts: You were born as a child of a foreign diplomat in the US on official service. That should be enough to satisfy the officer. They will not presume that you are a US citizen and you are not claiming that you are.

Comment: Thks for your clarification.